what if a term that is in the claims is too broadly defined in the specifications?
specifications:
X can be:

 1. A,
 2. B,
 3. C, or
 4. D

The term X is referenced in the claims.
The patent examiner decided that if X is interpreted to be A or B, then it's novel and non-obvious. But if X is interpreted to be C or D, then it is not novel or obvious.
At this point, can the inventor trim the specifications to remove C and D from the definition of X?
X can be:

 1. A, or
 2. B

No new matter was added to the specifications. Matter was instead just taken away.

In almost all such cases what you want is a claim that recites generically whatever is common to A, B, C, and D that makes the invention work. If, after sufficient head-scratching, it is determined that this cannot be done for some reason, then perhaps a Markush group that recites the contemplated alternatives is the next best solution. That way one would be amending the claim rather than the specification if it becomes necessary to tune the possibilities.
The specification should ideally make clear that A, B, C, and D are alternatives and any one of them may be used (or at least one or whatever the case may be).
By the way, the economic value of patents that fail to claim substantially all reasonable constructions that make the invention work is limited, because a would-be infringers can easily choose to use one of the combinations that is not covered by the patent. For example, in your hypothetical, once you've eliminated C and D as possibilities anyone can make and use those kinds of embodiments without infringing the resulting patent. To be able to collect royalties, it would have to be the case that use of A and B yield substantially greater value for the end user versus C or D.
